# How to make a jquery popup menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, popup

I am trying to make a Login popup window. For example, if someone clicked the login button a popup window will show and it will change the opacity of the main page and give focus to the popup window.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) is an example of a web site that utilizes what I want to implement.

Comment: I recommend starting with jQueryUI Dialog and then *altering it* as required (after it is created, not the jQueryUI source!) - in my case I strip most of the applied styles and add a custom close button. The jQueryUI dialog *correctly handles focus* and ESC, which many other alternatives do not. Better resizing can also be patched externally. Works very well in IE8+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the jquery dialog referenced in your post for this.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form) is an example of how to create form elements on it.

Answer (score 3):

you could use jqueryUI [dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog)

Comment: The latest version of jQuery UI is 1.8.1

Answer (score 1):

you could also use the jQuery BlockUI plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blockUI

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [Boxy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/) plugin before, it's very lightweight (lighter than JQueryUI, although not as much functionality).

It's very easy to use, it was the first plugin I used when learning jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

use this site link 
Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process. Embed form markup in the content area, set the modal option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the buttons option.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to jQuery's website, could you also provide the code necessary to answer to OP's question as well as an explanation on how/why it works?